# Прозрачность в css

Tags: html, css

При создании прямоугольника с сделал обводку, хотел изменить прозрачность середины, но чтобы обводка не была прозрачной

[![123][1]][1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff908;
  background-color: rgba(255, 249, 8, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

`background-color: rgba(255, 249, 8, 0.1);` - последний параметр `0.1` это значение прозрачности, устанавливается от 0 до 1. [Подробнее](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `rgba` для `background-color`: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)`. 
Последний параметр - альфа-канал (от 0 до 1).

А вы наверное используете `opacity` (для всего элемента).